# Neo4j 3.0 - Unable to start server on CentOS Machine

Tags: neo4j

I have started using Neo4j 3.0 version on Centos 6 with Java 1.8 versions. But, unfortunately I am unable to start the server.

And, in 2.3.3 version, I used to make couple of changes to neo4j-server.properties file to access the neo4j browser remotely. I could't find the file in 3.0 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.0 config file names and config option names changed significantly. See http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#deployment-upgrading for a config migration tool.

Comment: Added dbms.active_database=/root/neo4j.graphdb , But failed to load data. Server started but unable to fetch the data as expected.